# Styling a <select> in CSS Issues

Tags: html, css, select

I am using pure CSS to style a < select > drop down box.  Using the code below, I am able to do this with one hiccup: when the text on the option becomes too wide, it doesn't cut off before the background image of the drop down arrow.

[image: Normal View]

When the text is too long:

[image: Text too long]

What I would like to accomplish is to have the text cut off before the drop down arrow image so that they do not overlap.  However, I would still like the full text to display when the drop down list is expanded:

[image: Expanded]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Styling Selects</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .selectDiv select {
            background: transparent;
            width: 250px;
            padding: 7px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            height: 34px;
            text-transform: lowercase;
            color: #666666;
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .selectDiv {
            border: 2px solid #666666;
            display: block;
            width: 218px;
            height: 34px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position:relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .selectButtonDiv {
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            z-index: 99;
            position: absolute;
            left: 190px;
            top: 9px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: url("stream_7B0046.png") no-repeat -96px #FFF;
        }       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="selectDiv">
        <div class="selectButtonDiv"></div>
        <select>
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option With Really Long Name">Option With Really Long Name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how I could trim off the text when displaying the collapsed drop down box but still show the full text when expanded.  All this while remaining purely in CSS.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried padding-right ?

Comment: Padding-Right adds padding to the right of the original select drop down arrow, not between the text and the arrow.  So, it doesn't solve the need to hide the normal drop down arrow while displaying the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to make the `select` wide enough to account for your largest character count.  I'm sure you thought of that and it's not available.

My second recommendation is adding Javascript, particularly jQuery DD, to replace the `select options` with definition lists that can be more easily styled.  https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/jquery.dd

Comment: Ended up using a jQuery plugin (Chosen), so JS had to be the way to go.

Comment: @JohnChapman thanks for the tip on Chosen, I'll definitely start using that!

Answer (score 2):

Put the select in an inner div, and use padding-right on your existing selectDiv or margin-right on that inner div.

Comment: Can you post how you would do that?  When I try to do that it makes it so the div with the drop down image is no longer underneath the select (which makes it so when you click the image, the drop down no longer appears).

Comment: Add float: left to the inner div, or use a span instead of a div for that one. It's because it's clearing.

Comment: Sorry. On a mobile, so coding something more useful up's going to be a nightmare at the mo.